# Non linear Programming Problem

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

I am struggling with the following question:

Solve the following programing problem:

max $f(x_1,x_2)$= $ \sqrt{(x_1 + 1) (x_2+1)} $
subject to $x_2-(x_1-1)^2 \leq 0 $;
$x_1+x_2 \leq 7 $;
$x_1, x_2 \geq 0$
Using the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker condition, I can proof that the cases:
- $x_1 = 0 $ $x_2=0 $
- $x_1 = 0 $ $x_2 > 0$
- $x_1 > 0 $ $x_2 > 0$
Are not valid solutions for the problem.
But I don't get a hang on proofing the last case ($x_1 > 0; x_2 > 0$) and actually finding a solution algebraically for the problem. 
Thank you!

Comment: i got $\frac{9}{2}$ for $x_1=x_2=\frac{7}{2}$

Comment: but this solution does not satisfy the second constraint: $ x_1 + x_2 \leq 7$

Comment: @Raphael $\frac{7}{2}+\frac{7}{2}=7 \leq 7$

Comment: @ calculus: I was thinking about the same solution, but can you explain me how to justify this result algebraically.